# center text in editor after update in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to show text aligned in the center. the issue is that once I update the text it is getting cut off. 
If I use "Fill" as a HorizontalOptions the text is not going to get cut off but the text is not in the center.

Example is based on the editor sample in Forms:

```cs
public class EditorPageCode : ContentPage
{
    Editor styledEditor = new Editor();
    Editor centerText = new Editor();
    Editor customEditor = new Editor();

    public EditorPageCode()
    {
        var layout = new StackLayout { Padding = new Thickness(5, 10) };
        this.Title = "Editor Demo - Code";
        layout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "This page demonstrates the Editor View. The Editor is used for collecting text that is expected to take more than one line." });
        styledEditor = new Editor
        {
            Text = "Xamarin Blue",
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#2c3e50"),
            HeightRequest = 100,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
        customEditor = new Editor { Text = "Default starting text", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
        customEditor.Focused += StyledEntry_Focused;
        layout.Children.Add(customEditor);
        centerText = new Editor
        {
            IsEnabled = false,
            Text = "This is a disabled editor",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill

        };
        layout.Children.Add(centerText);
        this.Content = layout;
    }
    void StyledEntry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        var text = centerText.Text + "new ";
        centerText.Text = text;
        centerText.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried with **FillAndExpand** property?

Answer (score 0):

I actually looked into the sources. A solution which would work for me as I do not need editing on this specific Field is to use a label.

```
        centerText = new Label
        {
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            Text = "This is a disabled editor",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill

        };
```

The Label has the HorizontalTextAlignment which does keep the text in center after an update.
The Editor control does not have that.